# Añadir valores absolutos y porcentajes a las etiquetas de cada porción de una grafico de barras combinada

Tags: python, matplotlib

Buen día, estoy construyendo una gráfica de barras combinada (con tres campos) y quisiera agregar los valores de cada porción juntos con los porcentajes.

Ahora mismo hago lo siguiente:

```
result.groupby(['x1', 'x2'])['Campo1', 'Campo2', 'Campo3'].sum().plot.bar(figsize=(15, 7), stacked=True)

plt.title('titulo', fontsize=25)  # Titulo de la grafica
plt.ylabel('titulo', fontsize=20) # Titulo eje y
plt.xlabel('titulo', fontsize=20) # Titulo eje x
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.6), fontsize=16) #ubicación leyenda
plt.xticks(rotation=360, fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
plt.grid(True)
```

Quisiera agregar etiquetas de datos (valores y porcentajes), en cada color de cada barra.
[image: Grafica actual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución pasa por recorrer cada rectángulo mediante `axis.patches`, calcular el centro y agregar la etiqueta correspondiente con `axis.text`.

Para generar la etiqueta adecuada para cada uno, podemos obtener los valores del DataFrame en un array de NumPy, crear otro array calculando los valores relativos por filas y por último usamos `zip` sobre ambos arrays traspuestos y aplanados para que cada pareja (valor absoluto : valor relativo) coincida con el orden en el que retorna el rectángulo correspondiente `axis.patches`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DataFrame de ejemplo
result = pd.DataFrame({
    "x1": (1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 2),
    "x2": (1, 2, 9, 5, 7, 6),
    "Campo1": (45, 12, 17, 45, 17, 65),
    "Campo2": (24, 52, 14, 68, 42, 35),
    "Campo3": (56, 23, 24, 13, 17, 19)
})


group_sum = result.groupby(['x1', 'x2'])['Campo1', 'Campo2', 'Campo3'].sum()
ax = group_sum.plot.bar(figsize=(15, 7), stacked=True)

ax.set_title('titulo', fontsize=25)  # Titulo de la grafica
ax.set_ylabel('titulo', fontsize=20) # Titulo eje y
ax.set_xlabel('titulo', fontsize=20) # Titulo eje x
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.6), fontsize=16) #ubicación leyenda
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90, labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis="y", labelsize=15)
ax.grid(True)

abs_values = group_sum.values
rel_values = abs_values / abs_values.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) * 100

labels = zip(abs_values.T.flatten(), rel_values.T.flatten())

for path in ax.patches:
    abs_value, rel_value = next(labels)
    label = f"{rel_value:.2f}% ({abs_value})"
    width, height = path.get_width(), path.get_height()
    x, y = path.get_xy() 
    ax.text(x=x + width / 2, 
            y=y + height / 2, 
            s=label,
            horizontalalignment='center', 
            verticalalignment='center'
            )
plt.show()
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, me funciona a la perfección.